CW construction theorem. From J. M. Lee's book.
enter image description here
I have a question about the proof of Theorem 5.20 from John M. Lee's book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds".
I did not understand the proof of the uniqueness of cell decomposition with the indicated properties.
We prove the uniqueness of a cell decomposition of $X=\bigcup_n X_n$ such that the $n$-skeleton of $X$ is equal to $X_n$. $X_n$ here is the topological space obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching $n$-cells. But when we prove uniqueness, we must consider some arbitrary cell decomposition of $X$, so that simply the topological space $X_n$ will be equal to the n-skeleton of $X$. And in this case it is not clear why, for example, our “new” $n$-cells will be open in $X_n$, which, as I understand it, is necessary for the argument with connected components given in the proof.
On the previous page there is this theorem:
Let X be a $CW$ complex. Each skeleton $X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching a collection of $n$-cells.
It would help if we knew that our “new” partition of $X$ induces the structure of a $CW$ complex on the topological space $X_n$, but we have nothing of the kind at our disposal.
Perhaps, in the formulation of the theorem, what was meant was “a unique cell decomposition making it into a $CW$ complex whose $n$-skeleton is the $n$-skeleton of $X_n$ for each $n$"?
(Instead of “a unique cell decomposition making it into a $CW$ complex whose n-skeleton is $X_n$ for each $n$")

I don't understand the point you're trying to make. "The $n$-skeleton of $X_n$" is the same thing as "$X_n$" since $X_n$ is an $n$-dimensional complex.

@EricWofsey A priori, $X$ might have a cell partition such that its $n$-skeleton is equal to the $X_{n-1}$, considered simply as a subset and topological subspace, but not have the same cells.

@PreD the theorem talks about cell decomposition such that each $m$-skeleton is $X_m$. There is only one such decomposition.

Also cells in $X_n\backslash X_{n-1}$ are always open. Topologically this is a (potentially empty) disjoint unions of open balls. Lee considers $X_n\backslash X_{n-1}$ here, not $X_n$.

@PreD again: there is an assumption that $X_n$ form skeleton of the decomposition. There is no "homeomorphic" assumption, but literally: there is only cw decomposition such that $X_n$ are its skeleton. Or in other words: the collection of all cw decompositions having all $X_n$ as its skeleton contains a single element.

@freakish OK, if our assumption is that $n$-skeleton of $X$ must be equal to $X_n$ in sense of equality of cellular structure (not only as topological spaces) then it is clear.

It's actually the unique CW decomposition with the property that for each $n$, the $n$-skeleton, considered as a topological subspace of $X$, is $X_n$. This is because the cells are completely determined by knowing the subspaces $X_n$ for each $n$: The $n$-cells are exactly the connected components of $X_n \smallsetminus X_{n-1}$.  Once you know all the cells, you know the CW decomposition.

@JackLee Good evening! Thank you. >"The n-cells are exactly the connected components of $X_n \smallsetminus X_{n−1}$". This is obviously true if we know that $X_n$ is a CW complex. But if we consider an arbitrary cellular structure on the topological space $X_n$, about which it is only known that its k-skeleton coincides with the subspace $X_k \subset X_n$, then I do not see how to conclude that $X_n$ in this cellular decomposition is a CW complex. And, accordingly, how can we understand that $X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching n-cells, because Theorem 5.18 uses axoma W to show this.

@JackLee In this place of the proof we have not even show, that $X$ with chosen cell decomposition is CW complex (and therefore chosen cell decomposition is CW - decomposition) not to mention arbitrary cell decomposition, such that its $n$-skeleton is equal to $X_n$, considering simply as topological subspace.

@JackLee We also cannot say that $X_n$ with an arbitrary cellular partition such that its $k$-skeletons as a topological space coincide with $X_k \subset X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by adding $n$ cells. Because this can only be proven by assuming that $X_n$ is a CW complex, as done in 5.18. This does not follow from the conditions in the formulation of the proposition, because they talk about certain given adjunction spaces $X_0 \dots X_n \dots$, where each is obtained from the next by attaching cells, but we, proving uniqueness, must assume the existence of another cellular decomposition.

@JackLee As a result, we cannot say that $X_n$ in the “new” cell partition is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching $n$-cells (although $X_{n} \smallsetminus X_{n-1}$ - is a disjunctive union of “new” $n$-cells, but this is less than the content of the “attaching of $n$-cells” construction, which is a construction of adjunction space with its properties). And without the construction of attaching of $n$-cells (that is, de facto construction of a special factor-space), as well as without fulfilling (C) and (W), we have very little left, and it is not clear how we can prove anything.

I, however, found the key: this is the phrase “...unique cell decomposition making it into a CW complex...” in the wording of the statement. So we can assume that an “arbitrary” decomposition on $X$ is CW-decomposition. The confusion arises from the fact that at this point in the proof we have not yet shown that the specific decomposition that we are constructing is a CW-decomposition, and so it seems that uniqueness needs to be shown without assuming the fulfillment of (C) and (W).

@PreD: I'm not sure exactly what's bothering you. When I claim uniqueness, I've shown that $X$ has a cell decomposition such that $X_n$ is the $n$-skeleton for each $n$. The fact that $X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching some $n$-cells is part of the hypothesis, and I showed in the proof that each $n$-cell has an appropriate attaching map. If there were any other cell decomposition of $X$ with the property that $X_n$ is the $n$-skeleton (as a topological subspace) for each $n$, the $n$-cells would have to be the components of $X_n\smallsetminus X_{n-1}$, so they are the same cells.

The uniqueness of the cell decomposition actually has nothing to do with it being a CW decomposition -- at that point in the proof, I've shown that this is the unique cell decomposition with the property that $X_n$ is the $n$-skeleton for each $n$.

@JackLee >"The fact that $X_n$
is obtained from $X_{n−1}$
by attaching some $n$
-cells is part of the hypothesis". But this is part of the hypothesis when as cells for $X$ we take the cells from ${X_n}$ that are already given by consruction. But if we consider some other cell decomposition on $X$ such that its n-skeleton is equal to $X_n$ for all $n$, then why is "$X_n$ obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching n-cells"? At 5.18. You show this for CW structures. Here, perhaps, we need to prove this based on the fact that the 0-skeleton $X$ is topologically equal to the discrete set $X_0$?

@JackLee When I say "$X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n−1}$
by attaching $n$-cells" I mean factor-consruction, not simply the fact that $X_n \smallsetminus X_{n-1}$ consists of all $n$ -cells. What I mean is that if we consider another cell decomposition when proving uniqueness, the way I imagine it is that we need some kind of reasoning similar to Proposition 5.18
